# How to put text on a new line with multiple lines of text in one string

Tags: python

Hi I am making a chatbot in python and in my training for the bot i am trying to make a multiple choice question so i wanted the choices for the question to be on a new line, however using \n does not put it on a new line

my code looks like this

```
elena = ChatBot('elena')

questions=[
    'Yes',
    'Question one, is it \nA) blah blah \nB) blah blaah \nC) blah blah',
    'B (Correct Answer)',
  ] 

trainer = ListTrainer(elena)
trainer.train(questions)
```

Comment: It does if you `print(questions[1])`

Comment: Print strings one by one instead of printing the whole array - `[print(q) for q in questions]`

Comment: @matszwecja don't use list comprehensions for side-effects.

Comment: Would this work as im using this array to train my bot doing

trainer.train(questions)

Comment: Way too little information to answer this question.

Comment: Added more code